# The closure as parameter behind the default parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, parameters, closures, type-inference

I have a function

```
fun <T> get(path: String, params: MutableMap<String, Any>? = null, headers: MutableMap<String, String>? = null, resolver: ResponseResolver<T>): HttpRequest<T>
```

which ResponseResolver is a type alias

```
typealias ResponseResolver<T> = (HttpResponse) -> T
```

When i invoke the get method like below:

```
get("/somePath", mutableMapOf("key" to "value")){ httpResponse -> ......some code(Last line is a List<SomeClass>)
```

Then the Intellij tells me that

```
Type inference failed: 

fun <T> get
(
path: String,
params: MutableMap<String, Any>? = ...,
headers: MutableMap<String, String>? = ...,
resolver: ResponseResolver<T> /* = (HttpResponse) → T */
)
: HttpRequest<T>

cannot be applied to
(
String,
MutableMap<String, Any>,
(HttpResponse) → List<SomeClass>
)
```

[image: Intellij Hint]

I'm not sure if there is any strictions in applying the closure as the argument of some functions with default parameters.

Comment: Pay attention to the question marks, the `fun` expects a nullable `MutableMap<String, Any>?` but got a non-nullable `MutableMap<String, Any>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin don't know exactly what `mutableMapOf("key" to "value")` is.

Clarify whether it's params or headers

`get("/somePath", headers = mutableMapOf("key" to "value")){ httpResponse -> ......some code(Last line is a List<SomeClass>)`

or

`get("/somePath", mutableMapOf<String, Any>("key" to "value")){ httpResponse -> ......some code(Last line is a List<SomeClass>)`

Comment: Interesting, when i explicitly declare the type argument, the intellij hints "Remove explicit type argument". Now i know the problem lies in the lack of type arguments. Thank you!